# How to use infinispan as a remote session repository for Cipango Servlet engine?

Tags: jetty, session-state, infinispan, sip-servlet, cipango

I need to use infinispan in a remote node for keeping session states. how can I use it with Cipango? I know that jetty can use it, but what about Cipango? do 
I need additional configuration in Cipango?

I have seen some classes in Cipango source code with the name of Cipango-replication, what should I do with them? I'm not seeing this module in pom.xml of Cipango source code? how to add this module if it's necessary.

I also know that I would use a HotRod client in my servlet engine to read/write session states from/to Infinispan, but I have no Idea where to start it with Cipango?

Comment: Hmmm, no idea about Cipango. Maybe this is something you should specifically ask the Cipango guys via their support channels? :|

Comment: @GalderZamarreño Hey, do you have any idea about jetty and infinispan? I think I can go through any tutorial of Jetty+infinispan, then I will know what to do

Comment: I'm afraid I've not used Jetty before. My only experience is with Wildfly which stores web session data inside Infinispan, but it's very custom code.